# map view gets flipped horizontally swift

Tags: mkmapview, right-to-left

MKmapview and GSMmapview both get flipped horizontally when doing semantic content attribute is set RTL for application.

My application is in English and Arabic. For Arabic I have set semantic content attribute property to rtl. Now my map view also gets flipped horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have set the leading and trailing constraints correctly and you would just like to flip all views except the `MKmapview`,

1. If you have set up your map via Interface Builder, you can set (do this only for the map view) the view semantics to `Force Left-to-Right` as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HoUq.png).
2. Alternatively, if you have set up your map programmatically, you may also set the `semanticContentAttribute`

   ```
   let mapView = MKMapView()
   mapView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
   ```

The natural view semantics is `Left-to-Right`, so if you have set it to `Right-to-Left`, the view is going to be flipped.